# How to use JSF generated HTML element ID with colon ":" in CSS selectors?

Tags: css, jsf, css-selectors, facelets, clientid

I've been working with a simple Java EE project using JSF.

```
<h:form id="phoneForm">
    <h:dataTable id="phoneTable">

    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I tried to set CSS via `#phoneTable { ... }`, however it doesn't work. Upon inspection of the HTML source in client side, it appears that 
the JSF-generated HTML table gets a client ID in form of `id="phoneForm:phoneTable"`. I can't apply CSS via `#phoneForm:phoneTable { ... }`, because the colon indicates the start of a pseudoselector and causes an error.

How can I use it anyway in CSS selectors?

Comment: Why don't you add a `styleClass` attribute to your dataTable? - See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111388/the-css-selector-for-an-element-that-its-id-is-in-the-foobar-form

Comment: I've just add the colon: phoneForm\:phoneTable and it works. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `:` is a special character in CSS identifiers, it represents the start of a [pseudo class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes) like `:hover`, `:first-child`, etc. You would need to escape it.

```css
#phoneForm\:phoneTable {
    background: pink;
}
```

This only doesn't work in IE6/7. If you'd like to support those users as well, use `\3A` instead (with a trailing space behind!)

```css
#phoneForm\3A phoneTable {
    background: pink;
}
```

Above works in all browsers.

---

There are several other ways to solve this:

1. Just wrap it in a plain HTML element and style via it instead.

   ```html
    <h:form id="phoneForm">
        <div id="phoneField">
            <h:dataTable id="phoneTable">
   ```

   with

   ```css
    #phoneField table {
        background: pink;
    }
   ```

   ---
2. Use `class` instead of `id`. E.g.

   ```html
    <h:dataTable id="phoneTable" styleClass="pink">
   ```

   with

   ```css
    .pink {
        background: pink;
    }
   ```

   or

   ```css
    table.pink {
        background: pink;
    }
   ```

   Additional advantage is that this allows much more abstraction freedom. The CSS is reusable on multiple elements without the need to add selectors and/or copypaste properties when you want to reuse the same properties on another element(s).

   ---
3. Since JSF 2.x only: change the JSF default `UINamingContainer` separator by the following context param in `web.xml`. E.g.

   ```xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
        <param-value>-</param-value>
    </context-param>
   ```

   So that the separator character becomes `-` instead of `:`.

   ```css
    #phoneForm-phoneTable {
        background: pink;
    }
   ```

   Disadvantage is that you need to ensure that you don't use this character yourself anywhere in the ids and this is thus a very brittle approach. I do **not** recommend this approach. This is a bad practice.

   ---
4. Since JSF 1.2 only: disable prepending of the form `id`.

   ```html
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <h:dataTable id="phoneTable">
   ```

   so that you can use

   ```css
    #phoneTable {
        background: pink;
    }
   ```

   Disadvantage is that `<f:ajax>` won't be able to find it and that it is considered poor practice: [UIForm with prependId="false" breaks <f:ajax render>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render). I do **not** recommend this approach. This is a bad practice. Moreover, this attribute does not exist in all other `UINamingContainer` components, so you still have to deal with them the right way (#1 and/or #2 here above).

   ---

In *your* specific case, I think turning it into a CSS class as described in #2 is the most appropriate solution. A "phone table" namely doesn't seem to represent a website-wide unique element. Real website-wide unique elements such as header, menu, content, footer, etc are usually not wrapped in JSF forms or other JSF naming containers, so their IDs wouldn't be prefixed anyway.

#### See also:

- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-jsf-components-using-jquery)
- [By default, JSF generates unusable IDs, which are incompatible with the CSS part of web standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726653/by-default-jsf-generates-unusable-ids-which-are-incompatible-with-css-part-of/)

Comment: Thank you! Especially for 2. and 3. part of your answer since for me escaping did not work and using a class is less efficiant in rendering.

Comment: Thank you! It was useful for a command button inside a form. The command button render a **span** tag. I set the css style like: `#form-id span`

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:form prependId="false">
```

Does not work if you are using a

```
<h:commandButton>
tag
```