# <h:inputText> render problem in a form

Tags: jsf, facelets

i have a question about rendering a simple `<h:inputText>` value. When i write

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{userBean.user.username}" />
```

it's output is

```
<input id="form:username" name="form:username" type="text" />
```

is there a way for an output without `form:xxx` like this?

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
```

Also minlength is not working with `<h:inputText>`. do you have an idea without writing javascript for each data in form?

Comment: Just curious, why exactly do you want to get rid of the prepended ID?

Comment: hi BalusC, the reason is beacuse of my jquery validation script. when i write <h:inputText id="pass".. its output <input id="form:pass" so validation isn't working interestingly.. when output is <input id="pass" it works. i think i need to change my validator plugin.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors

Comment: balusC, thank you so much. i think as a newbie I will ask these simple questions and we will meet again many times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You should add **prependId** attribute inside h:form

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="form1">
Now everything won't have prefix form1
</h:form>
```

Comment: It's a pleasure to help others!