# f:ajax within ui:repeat, unknown id for the component

Tags: jsf-2

When I try to render a panelGroup by an ajax call, it gives unknown id.

```
<h:form id="form1" prependId=false>
  <h:panelGroup id="panel1">
       <h:dataTable/>
       <ui:repeat value="#{bean.page}" var="page">
          <h:commandLink value="#{page}">
              <f:ajax execute="@form" render="panel1" listener="#{bean.page}" />
          </h:commandLink>
       </ui:repeat>
  </h:panelGroup>     
 </h:form>
```

When I tried this code, it gives unknown id panel1. I tried with id ":panel1" too. I get the same error.

Comment: Why did you edit your code to move the `</h:panelGroup>` to the other end?

Comment: The ui:repeat is inside the panelGroup. So, I had to move to the other end.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the code snippet in my answer as well. But the technical answer remains the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A relative client ID (i.e. not starting with `:`) is relative to the current parent [`NamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) component. The `<ui:repeat>` is also a `NamingContainer`. So the `render="panel1"` is looking for the component within the context of `<ui:repeat>`. This isn't going to work. An absolute client ID (i.e. starting with `:`) is looking for the component within the context of view root. But you've it inside a `<h:form>` -which is in turn another `NamingContainer` component-, so the `render=":panel"` is also not going to work.

The following should work, with `prependId="false"` removed so that you can refer it:

```
<h:form id="form1">
  <h:panelGroup id="panel1">
    <h:dataTable/>

    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.page}" var="page">
      <h:commandLink value="#{page}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":form1:panel1" listener="#{bean.page}" />
      </h:commandLink>
    </ui:repeat>
  </h:panelGroup> 
</h:form>
```

By the way, if you *actually* want to render **only** the table, then you should be doing this:

```
<h:form id="form1">
  <h:panelGroup>
    <h:dataTable id="table1" />

    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.page}" var="page">
      <h:commandLink value="#{page}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":form1:table1" listener="#{bean.page}" />
      </h:commandLink>
    </ui:repeat>
  </h:panelGroup> 
</h:form>
```

---

**Update**: as per the comments, it turns out that you have changed the JSF default `NamingContainer` separator character from `:` to `_` by configuration. In that case, you need to use `_` instead of `:` in the client ID selector.

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="_form1_panel1" listener="#{bean.page}" />
```

Comment: I removed prependId="false" for the form tag. I get the exception,
javax.faces.FacesException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':form1:panel1' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt228.

Comment: Then the `<h:form>` is by itself apparently located in another `NamingContainer` component. Rightclick the page in browser, do *View Source* and locate the `<span id="....:form1:panel1">` and use exactly that ID with `:` prefixed.

Comment: <h:form> is located in <ui:composition>. Is there a way to find out which naming container is it located in?

Comment: Checking HTML source is really the easiest for starters who don't understand the `NamingContainer` concept. Do as I said in an earlier comment, do a *View Source* of the JSF-generated HTML source in the webbrowser and locate the `<span>` element which JSF has generated for `<h:panelGroup id="panel1">`. You should use exactly that HTML ID (the client ID) prefixed with `:` in the `render` attribute.

Comment: For the commandlink, I used FacesContext to get current instance and traced the parent component for form which is ViewRoot.

Comment: Sigh. Look in the HTML source. What's the generated ID of the `<h:panelGroup id="panel1">`?

Comment: The panelGroup id is <span is="form_panel1">

Comment: OK, you've apparently changed your JSF configuration to use `_` as naming container separator character. This way you need to use `render="_form_panel1"` instead.

Comment: I used render="_form_panel1". It is working now. Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: You're welcome. If the reason of changing the default separator character from `:` to `_` was to overcome CSS selector issues, then you may find this answer useful which shows the alternative ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Finally I fully understand the case

Comment: Is there a way that doesn't remove prependId="false"? My form has prependId=false and the render=":thePanelGroupIdThatWrapsUIRepeat" but it still refreshes the page.

Comment: @Emerald214: just never use `prependId`. It's an unthoughtful leftover of JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui:repeat value="#{interaction.interactionListBean}" var="interactionItr"> 

    <h:commandLink value="#{interactionItr.interactionDate}"  styleClass="#{interaction.createImage}" style="margin:0 5px 5px 0!important; display:inline-block;"><br/>
        <f:ajax  render=":formId:interactionDate :formId:category :formId:activity :formId:status :formId:channel :formId:status1 :formId:caseId :formId:comment :formId:user1 :formId:team :formId:user :formId:transit "  
                    listener="#{interactionController.interactionDetailGet}"/> 
        <f:param name="RefId" value="#{interaction.interactionRefId}"/> 
    </h:commandLink>

</ui:repeat>
```

problem :
please refer above with above code their is no exception on console but the ajax listerner will not invoke when I saw this post similiar kind of concept being use just I was place the exceute="@form" then my coding is working fine

solution:

`execute="@form"`