# JSF 2.0 h:panelgroup render by h:commandButton through f:ajax, which is inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2

```
<h:panelGroup id="userPanel" >
   <ui:repeat value="#{searchView.userList}" var="user" rowKeyVar="index" >
     //other code   
     <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{searchAction.doFindUsers}"   >
        <f:ajax execute="@this" event="action" render="userPanel" />
    </h:commandButton>
   </ui:repeat>
```

When I use render inside the ui:repeat tag it is showing the following error

`<f:ajax>` contains an unknown id 'userPanel' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt870

Comment: This is probably what you are searching for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088273/fajax-within-uirepeat-unknown-id-for-the-component

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie thank you.It's working, by adding `render=":form:userPanel"`But I have a question on this, why we need to add `:` before `form`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify a client ID without `:` prefix, it's searched relative to the parent [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) component. In your code, the `<ui:repeat>` is the closest parent `NamingContainer`. However, the component which you're actually targeting is not inside the `<ui:repeat>`, instead it's outside the `<ui:repeat>`. That explains why it cannot be found using a relative client ID.

You need to specify an absolute client ID instead. For starters, an easy way to figure it out is locating the HTML representation of the JSF component in the generated HTML output, grabbing its `id` and prefixing it with `:`. Prefixing with `:` makes it an absolute client ID which will always be resolved relative to `UIViewRoot` instead of the closest parent `NamingContainer`.

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)