# PrimeFaces: how to override CSS class

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, styling

When a button is created, the class `ui-corner-all` is always applied. I tried the following:

```
<p:commandButton id="like" styleClass="ui-corner-right" />
```

but it didn't work. On Firebug, I saw both `ui-corner-all` and `ui-corner-right`:

```
<div id="form1:like" type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-corner-right">
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Following the hint from JMelnik, I finally succeeded to change the style of `ui-corner-all` to `ui-corner-right` by adding the following script:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myForm\:likeButton .ui-corner-all {
        border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px !important;
    }
</style>
```

and wrap the `<p:commandButton>` inside `<h:panelGroup>` as following:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="likeButton">
        <p:commandButton />
    <h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to BalusC's suggestion, the following solution should be better:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .likeButton .ui-corner-all {
        border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px !important;
    }
</style>  

<h:panelGroup styleClass="likeButton">
    <p:commandButton />
<h:panelGroup>
```

Best regards,

Comment: try loading your css file in the end for example in the `<h:body>` and also , make sure you override the needed attribute that are defined by `ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ` INMO in your case you better don't try manipulate css from js

Comment: The `\:` doesn't work in MSIE. Such a button can hardly be totally unique in your view. Rather use a classname.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-re-write-those-class-defined-in-primefaces-css and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use a standard CSS override way.**

Include a *.css in your page, where you redefine `ui-corner-all` and `ui-corner-right` classes.

```
.ui-corner-all {
    //ovverides to nothing, you can also define any properties you want here
}

.ui-corner-right {
    //define properties  which would override unwanted behaviour
}
```

You can also apply additional css class which would override undesired properties.

Comment: Hmm... you mean I have to override the properties of `ui-corner-all` with that of `ui-corner-right`? Are there any ways to delete the `ui-corner-all` from the generated HTML?

Comment: You could use javascript/jquery to "removeClass('ui-corner-all')" on items that have it. That's a bit messy though and depends on the users having javascript enabled.

You could also use firebug to grab the CSS styles that "ui-corner-all" applies and then overwrite them all in your own CSS. Just repeating what JMelnik said here though.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes which solution did you use?

Comment: @JMelnik which one are you talking about :)

Comment: Did you override .ui-corner-all?

Comment: @JMelnik yes. check out the updates in my answer. That's what I have done.