# how to change radio buttons style in h:selectOneRadio

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

i have **h:selectOneRadio** as follows:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
<h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" id="sel_radio" value="#{mBean.selectedRadio}">  
   <f:selectItem id="option1" itemLabel="item1" itemValue="1" />  
   <f:selectItem id="option2" itemLabel="item2" itemValue="2" />            
</h:selectOneRadio>
.
.
.
</div>
```

above will be rendered as follows:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="myForm:sel_radio" id="myForm:sel_radio:0" value="1">
```

**ISSUE:** the container class gives default width for all inputs, that will affect on my radio button, here's the css class:

```
.container input {
width: 200px;
}
```

and i can't change this class because it's a template and used in other pages, i want to override this style in this page only.

i tried to override it as by adding following style:

```
.container #myForm:sel_radio:0 {
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work too.

please advise how to fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
<input type="radio" name="myForm:sel_radio" id="myForm:sel_radio:0" value="1">
```

you have to put backslash like this

```
.container  #myForm\:sel_radio\:0{
width:100px!important;
}
```

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh As I said in my answer I'm not sure if IE7 has this problem, but why not to support all of the browsers when it's simple as adding 2 more characters ?

Comment: Don't work in IE6/7. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors

Answer (score 4):

You'd better specify the element type, not the element ID:

```css
.container input[type=radio] {
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

Or, give it a styleclass such as `<h:selectOneRadio styleClass="myradio">`, with this CSS:

```css
.container .myradio input {
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape your colons with `\3A` (hexadecimal code of backslash) , since colon is a special character in CSS or you can define a new style:

```
 #myForm .container input { 
   width: 50px;
 }
```

Escaping colons with backslash directly `\` is not working in IE6 and I'm not sure if also in IE7.
Also avoid using **!important** if it is possible. It can cause headaches if you will try to change your styles after some time and you forgot about it.