# Override/implement CSS with JSF and PrimeFaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I use JSF and PrimeFaces and I try to modify render by changing or adding some CSS lines.

I added my CSS file named "styles.css" to my .xhtml page and it's loaded after those of PrimeFaces so I can override default values.

PrimeFaces create a div in my page :

```
<div id="j_idt13:universe" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="width: 86px;">
....
</div>
```

I'm trying to change 86px size to 100% so in my styles.css I added :

```
#j_idt13:universe{
    width: 100%;    
}
```

but it doesn't work...With Firebug when I inspect source code, my  #j_idt13:universe doesn't appear anywhere...

I can change some CSS by accessing class selector(.class) but not with id selector (#id).

In my case, how can I change 86px to 100% please ?

Thanks

Olivier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon `:` is a special character in [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) representing the start of a pseudo selector. If you want to represent the colon literally as part of the element ID or class name, then you have to escape it using `\`.

```css
#j_idt13\:universe {

}
```

Note that this doesn't work in IE6/7. You'd need to use `\3A`  instead (with a trailing space).

```css
#j_idt13\3A universe {

}
```

Also note that this will fail when you add another JSF component to the view, because `j_idt13` is an autogenerated ID depending on the component's position in the view, not a fixed ID. Rather give the parent `UINamingContainer` component a fixed ID, or better, give the target component a style class, so that you can just use the class selector.

#### See also:

- [How to use JSF generated HTML element ID with colon ":" in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors)