# css unknow property "rendered" on af:panelList

Tags: html, css, jsf

I'm trying to set the rendered attribute of `af:panelList` on a CSS file so I can't display it according to the device resolution but when I define on CSS:

```
#pl2 {
    rendered:false;
}
```

I get a unknown property "rendered" and chrome doesn't hide it when its a smaller resolution.

Heres the component definition on my .jspx file:

```
<af:panelList  id="pl2" rows="3" maxColumns="5" >
```

What can i do to fix this? Is there a way around?

Comment: JSF generates HTML. CSS works on HTML, not on JSF. Open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*. You'll see the JSF-generated HTML which is exactly what CSS is also seeing. You should base off your CSS on exactly that HTML. Further, `rendered` is definitely not a valid CSS property. See also http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/

Comment: I did what u told me, it renders a div with id pt1:panelobile and then a table which has no id. i added this line to the css
#pt1:panelmobile
{
  display: none;
}

but i have no luck so far, heres the inspected element
<div id="pt1:panelmobile" class="x3q" style="position:absolute;width:auto;height:auto;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" summary="">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *it renders a div with id pt1:panelobile and then a table which has no id. i added this line to the css #pt1:panelmobile { display: none; } but i have no luck so far*

If you ignore deprecated browsers like IE6/7, then you should be using this selector instead:

```css
#pt1\:panelmobile {
    display: none;
}
```

The `:` is namely a special character in CSS selectors indicating a pseudo selector and therefore needs to be escaped by `\` when used as-is.

But, especially in your particular case, much better is to just assign the JSF component a more generic and better reusable style class.

```html
<af:panelList ... styleClass="hidden">
```

with

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to use JSF generated HTML element ID with colon ":" in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors)

Comment: now it works! thank you so much! if I could i would buy u a beer :P thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to hide the element, try:

```
#pl2
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: i tried that already but it won't disapear, can't seem to find the problem with this one

Comment: There is most likely no such element with `id="pl2"` in the HTML. Apparently you've placed the responsible JSF component in a JSF form or some other naming container component, causing its client ID to be prepended.

Comment: try to inspect element with firebug or with chrome inspect tool and then get the element id

Comment: i inspected the element and it seems like it creates a div, 
 <div id="pt1:panelmobile" class="x3q" style="position:absolute;width:auto;height:auto;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;righ‌​t:0px"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" summary="">
i added to the css these lines:
#pt1:panelmobile
{
  display: none;
}
but it just wont work, dont know what to do :S

Comment: try using the class to get the element, insted of "#pt1:panelmobile" use ".x3q"