# Colon (:) in id name when using jsplumb

Tags: primefaces, escaping, jsplumb

I am using jsplumb and Primefaces. I have a number of p:panel components generated as part of a ui:repeat. I then want to connect these panels together using jsplumb. Primefaces generates the panel ids and I then use these in the script code to setup jsplumb.

When I use a panel id that I create everything works fine but I I use a panel id created automatically no connectors appear.

```
<ui:repeat value={#mybean.nodes} var="node"> <p:panel> ... </p:panel> </ui:repeat>

jsPlumb.connect({source:"j_idt20:0", target:"j_idt20:1"});
```

where j_idt20:0 and j_idt20:1 are generated ids from Primefaces and found by inspecting html page on browser.

I think I've tracked the issue down to the fact that the generated ids contain ':'. For example 'j_idt_29:0'

How do I reference ids with : in the name within jsplumb in the `jsPlumb.connect({source:"element1"target:"element2"});` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to escape the `:` with `\\` (if that wont work try single `\`)

```
jjsPlumb.connect({source:"j_idt20\\:0", target:"j_idt20\\:1"});
```

or

> change the JSF default UINamingContainer separator by the following
>   context param in web.xml. E.g.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
    <param-value>-</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[How to use JSF generated HTML element ID in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882502/617373)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I tried replacing : with // and / but this didn't work. I also tried the escapeClientId function suggested by partlov but this didn't work either but changing the default separator worked great. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `:` sign in you strings. Primefaces has buil-in JavaScript function for this. You can do following:

```
var escapedId = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId("id1:id2");
```

It will be escaped properly.

If you don't want to use this function, for some reason, escape `:` with `\\`:

```
"id1\\:id2"
```