# JSF doesn't read external css file

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resources

i have an external CSS file in the resources folder under WebContent folder, and i included it at the page header as follows:

```
<h:head>
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" library="css" />
</h:head>
```

i tried a simple selector to test the if the file is working like `body {background-color:#b0c4de;}` but unfortunately the file isn't linked

for more clarity i included here a screenshot for the exact location of the resources folder

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this is not an external CSS file at all. It's internal to your web application. A real external CSS file would be served from a different domain and is not importable via `<h:outputStylesheet>`, but only via `<link>`.

Your concrete problem is caused because you unnecessarily repeated the CSS file folder into the `library` attribute. Just get rid of it.

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
```

The `library` attribute must represent the common module/theme/library name, such as "primefaces", but you don't have any here. Using a library name of "css" makes no utter sense as "css" just represents the file/content type.

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template/8368727#8368727)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: ok, i have applied different attributes to an <p:inputText id="globalFilter" value="Search"/> as follows: #globalFilter {
margin-left: 995px;
margin-top:-30px;
width:320px;
height:20px;
font-size: 11px;
} but the element doesn't affected at all, do you know the reason?

Comment: This problem is completely unrelated to the question being asked. The CSS file is now successfully loaded, right? As to the new problem, just rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to look at JSF-generated HTML output. Do you see any HTML element with `id="globalFilter"` which the CSS rule is expecting? See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5878692/ Press `Ask Question` if you still stucks.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" library="css" />

here is a ref:
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/