# Adding style to specific p:panelGrid row

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I use JSF with PrimeFaces 3.5. I use the `p:panelGrid` without the `columns` attribute, instead I explicitly create rows and columns with `p:row` and `p:column`, as demonstrated in the showcase (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml).

Now I need to style one row differently with the help of some CSS class. But either I am missing it or there is just no way to add a class to a `p:row`?! I can even set the attribute `styleClass`, but it is ignored in the rendered output ...

Is there a way to somehow distinguish a row within a `panelGrid` by its class?

Comment: just wondering if you can abuse the *primefaces pass through attribute* like this `<p:row pt:class="mySpecialClass".....` http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2714 b.t.w if its only one row you can style it using its unique id...

Comment: We are "still" using JSF 2.1 (JEE 6), so we can't make use of this idea, although I will keep an eye on that. And for the row, I don't even have a unique ID. And even if I had one, I wouldn't know it, so I couldn't attach a style to it ...

Comment: i edited my answer if your customers won't use IE you can use it i think

Comment: Is there anything particular you gain from using p:panelGrid? You can always go with explicit xhtml tags and assign classes with no restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the `styleClass` attribute is ignored by default (at least until PrimeFaces version 6.2), but you can create a custom renderer that appends its value to the HTML output. A simple drop in replacement for the default PrimeFaces renderer looks like this:

```
public class PanelGridBodyRowRenderer extends CoreRenderer implements HelperRowRenderer {

    @Override
    public void encode(FacesContext context, Row row) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        String rowStyleClass = PanelGrid.TABLE_ROW_CLASS;
        String userRowStyleClass = row.getStyleClass();
        if (userRowStyleClass != null) {
            rowStyleClass = rowStyleClass + " " + userRowStyleClass;
        }

        writer.startElement("tr", row);
        writer.writeAttribute("class", rowStyleClass, null);
        writer.writeAttribute("role", "row", null);
        renderChildren(context, row);
        writer.endElement("tr");
    }

}
```

For PrimeFaces version 6.2 you can simply create this renderer class within the package `org.primefaces.component.row.renderer` in your WAR. The classloader will then load your renderer instead of the identical renderer class within the PrimFaces JAR.

For more information on custom components and renderers see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25629565/5223047) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a wild card on the css (to math all `td` that ends with your id)

Like this (select all td that its id ends with `myRowId`)

```
tr[id*='myRowId'] {
    color:red 
}
```

Here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/WmGtZ/)

---

Previous answer...

Since you can't use styleClass on `p:row` you can try the following

Assign that `p:row` an id, like this : `<p:row id="myRowId "`

And apply the style in the following way (in your css file)

```
#myFormId\3A SomeNamingContainer\3A myRowId {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Do view source of your page in order to replace the `myFormId` and `SomeNamingContainer` with your real ids...

Also read this : [How to use JSF generated HTML element ID in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882502/617373)

Comment: That would allow me to do it for one row, thanks. But if I have several rows or that same logic within several different `p:panelGrid`s, I would have dozens of CSS rules ... :-(

Answer (score -1):

If you need the same style in others rows, maybe you can work with the column style from `p:column` (according with your response to Daniel). Something like this:

```
.stylePerColumn {
    background-color: #F22626;
    color: black;
    border-style: none !important;
}
```

and int the xhtml file `<p:column styleClass="stylePerColumn ">...</p:column>` (to each column needed).