# jQuery to close tooltip in JSF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I am trying to close tooltip using jQuery hide.

On the tooltip, I put a image with `onclick` event that calls javascript function to hide the tooltip

```
<img id=... src=... onclick="hideTooltip('formId:tableId:rowIndex:tooltipId')" />
```

Here is the javascript function

```
function hideTooltip(elem) {
  var pound = '#';
  jQuery(pound.concat(elem.replace(/:/g, '\\\\:'))).hide('slow');
}
```

The js function is called as if I put a `alert`, it will pop up but `hide()` doesn't work. When I inspect the elements the id of the tooltip is `form:table:rowIndex#:tooltipId`.

I tried to use `widgetVar` and it will hide the tooltip but the tooltip shows data based on just the last row and not of each row.

```
<img ... onclick="PF('widgetVarID').hide()" />
```

Comment: _" doesn't work"_ means? and are you sure the id of the tooltip is `form:table:rowIndex#:tooltipId`? That is **not** the id you try to hide (the # is not after the rowIndex)

Comment: @Kukeltje By doesn't work, I mean it won't hide. I inspected element and id of the tooltip is the same as the one being passed to the `hideTooltip` (I verified by using `alert`)

Comment: It was not, the pound sign was in the middle…

Comment: @Kukeltje My bad. That was an typo. By rowIndex#, I meant for example `form:table:0:tooltipId, form:table:1:tooltipId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. The correct format should be '\:'

Replace with `pound.concat(elem.replace(/:/g, '\\:'));`

You can also use `PrimeFaces.escapeClientId()`.

Check [How to use JSF generated HTML element ID with colon ":" in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-with-colon-in-css-selectors)