# How to remove id auto integrated of <h:form> in JSF?

Tags: forms, jsf-2.2

I have `<h:form prependId="false" id="productDescription">` and when rendered to html:

```
<form id="j_idt143:0:productDescription" name="j_idt143:0:productDescription" method="post" action="/WatchesStore/product-detail.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

I want clear `id:"j_idt143:0:"` after rendered to html. Please help me solved this problem.

Comment: Are you using template feature for this form ? Or this form inside some other component ?

Comment: yes, i'm using template for this page!

Comment: So some other component or DIV or something else is top of this form that why its adding that component id

Comment: i will review my code, thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is easier answerable with the correct answer if you elaborate the **why** on *"I want clear id:"j_idt143:0:" after rendered to html"*, because this indicates a strong http://xyproblem.info. For example, your actual problem might be http://stackoverflow.com/q/6045307 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/5878692

Answer (score -3):

```
<h:form prependId="false">
```

Change 
`id="j_idt143:0:productDescription"`
 to 
`id="productDescription"`

Comment: Please explain in more detail.

Comment: And it is wrong.