# Selenium use regex to locate custom attribute

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

```
<button class="hbutton" h:click="app.items(client.monthlyItems)" style="">Start</button>
```

How do I use regex in css locator to find h:click="app.items(client.monthlyItems)" for class=hbutton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to escape the colon (:). You can use the CSS Selector below.

```
"h1[h\\:click='app.items(client.monthlyItems)']"
```

[How to use JSF generated HTML element ID with colon ":" in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-with-colon-in-css-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what language binding you are using, but you should be able to use xpath to find what you need. Here's an example in python: Try something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//@*[contains(., 'app.items(client.monthlyItems)')]")
```

You can also try a `starts-with`

```
//*[@*[starts-with(., 'app.items')]]
```

More details [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)

Comment: I have tried this it does not work because atrribute has ":". I am trying to find regex to locate it

Comment: Okay I have updated the answer to check with any attribute that contains. See if that works ..