# How do I remove inherited content using classes in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a new website (used HTML) which has an accordion. In the accordion, there is an image gallery (both use CSS & JS. I am new to JS). The accordion uses Unicode characters (minus to be precise) to display whether it's going to open or close.

Problem: The dots at the bottom of the gallery inherit the minus character from another class.

I've tried to remove the minus by a separate class by setting specifically the `content` to `none` (`content: none;`) in the css-file.

```
.active:after .test {
  content: none;
}
```

I added the class to the corresponding part of HTML code where the problem occurs:

```
<div style="text-align:center" class="active:after test">
```

This code doesn't work. *How do I properly create a class with selectors and add it to the HTML-element to remove the 'minus' from the dots?*

Snippet of code:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("imgSlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgSlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

.active:after .test {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Gallerie </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="site-container">
    <div class="page-container">
      <button class="accordion">Pictures 1</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="slideshow-container">
          <div class="imgSlides">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=1">
          </div>
          <div class="imgSlides">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2">
          </div>
          <div class="imgSlides">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=3">
            <div class="galerytext">placeholder</div>
          </div>
          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center" class="active:after test">
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: Added snippet.

Comment: You have to provide a [mcve] directly in the question.  Your question and the given answer should also help future readers, but external links can become invalid.

Comment: I have tried to provide a minimal reproducible example in the question

Comment: I added a snippet to the code so it's possible for everyone to run it & see my problem. If this still does not help to get this post off "[on hold]" please clarify what I need to add. I fail to understand why it's marked as off-topic, can somebody please enlighten me?
 I am a beginner to stackoverflow, so I'd really like to get feedback what I could do better next time when posting something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close but your CSS had a couple of issues.  First, you have to escape the colon in your selector: `.active\:after` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-with-colon-in-css-selectors) for more info) and you needed to remove the space between that and `.test`.  With this fix, you are now selecting the dots parent node.  From there is is just a matter of selecting the `.active:after` and setting its contents to `none` like this:

```css
.active\:after.test .active:after {
  content: none; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
}
```

A slightly simpler approach would be to do this in place of the above:

```css
.dot.active:after{
  content: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my mistakes I made. I fixed my code now and it's working thanks to your detailed explanation.