# Disabling input fields in a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, liferay-6

I have recently upgraded to Liferay 6.0, JSF 2.1 and jQuery 1.7.

Here is my html form:

```
 <h:form id="fundRequestForm" action="" method="post">
      <!-- Inside this I have various form field -->
    </h:form>
```

The form generated in the html page source:

```
<form id="_jpfcpncuivr_A2262_j_id1:fundRequestForm" name="_jpfcpncuivr_A2262_j_id1:fundRequestForm"
method="post" action="">
</form>
```

I want to disable all the input fields in a form other than the hidden form fields.

here is my javascript for that

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery('form#_jpfcpncuivr_A2262_j_id1:fundRequestForm input[type!="hidden"]').attr('disabled', 'true');
});
```

The input fields are not getting disabled. Please let me know what is wrong in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While valid in HTML element IDs/names, the colon is a special character in CSS selectors as it represents the start of pseudo selector. You need to escape it in CSS selectors.

```
jQuery('form#_jpfcpncuivr_A2262_j_id1\\:fundRequestForm input[type!="hidden"]').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

#### See also:

- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery/7928290#7928290) (for a more detailed answer with alternatives)
- [By default, JSF generates unusable ids, which are incompatible with css part of web standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726653/by-default-jsf-generates-unusable-ids-which-are-incompatible-with-css-part-of) (someone else ranted that it was standards-incompatible, but the answer proved it wrong)

Comment: And also do you recommend me using prop over attr?

Comment: In *your particular case* both works as good. The major difference is in retrieving values only. The general recommended way is however to prefer `prop()` over `attr()`. But again, this won't make any difference in *your particular case*. For more detail, see [`jQuery.prop()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a class to it:

```
<h:form id="fundRequestForm" action="" method="post" class="someClass">
  <!-- Inside this I have various form field -->
</h:form>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery('.someClass input').prop('disabled', true); //<-- use prop NOT attr
});
```

Comment: But this form element ID is auto generated especially "_jpfcpncuivr_A2262_j_id1:". This gets appended to the form ID given above "fundRequestForm"

Comment: And also could you please tell me the difference between using prop and attr?

Comment: @Sri [See here for the BIG differences between prop and attr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731)