# Is there a common replacement for javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, jsf

I don't like how JSF uses the colon to separate ID's in generated HTML, as it collides with CSS and JavaScript Selectors. And I don't like the idea of always escaping it. Thus I would like to replace it by some other character. Are there any drawbacks? And is there a common replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I don't like how JSF uses the colon to separate ID's in generated HTML, as it collides with CSS and JavaScript Selectors. And I don't like the idea of always escaping it.*

Just select elements by classname then? Is the HTML element's nature *really* so unique that it requires being selected by an ID? This is usually only the case for main layout components.

---

> *Thus I would like to replace it by some other character. Are there any drawbacks? And is there a common replacement?*

You can use any character you want, provided that it's valid in HTML element ID/name which is [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) as follows:

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Next to the colon, the only sensible choices are the hyphen, the underscore and the period. As the period is at its own also a special character in CSS selectors, it would have the same problem as the colon. So logically you don't have much other choice than the hyphen `-` and the underscore `_`.

As to the drawbacks, certainly there are drawbacks. You need to ensure that you are **not** using the new separator character anywhere in JSF component IDs like so `<h:someComponent id="foo_bar" />` in case of `_`. Those characters are namely [allowed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setId%28java.lang.String%29) in JSF component IDs (the colon isn't). It would break the `UIComponent#findComponent()` lookup.

#### See also:

- [By default, JSF generates unusable ids, which are incompatible with css part of web standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726653/by-default-jsf-generates-unusable-ids-which-are-incompatible-with-css-part-of/10726774#10726774)

Answer (score 3):

Well... based on a short googling for the `javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR` value

It seems that the preferred values are `-` or `_` (at least for **BalusC**)

> You only need to guarantee that you don't use it anywhere in JSF
>   component IDs yourself

[By default, JSF generates unusable ids, which are incompatible with css part of web standards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726774/617373)

[How to use JSF generated HTML element ID in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors)

[Disadvantages of JSF, a bit of history](http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2010/09/disadvantages-of-jsf-bit-of-history.html)

Comment: Are there any drawbacks, when using a `-` or a `_`?

Comment: Nope, And I don't think the following http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=490 is something that you should consider as a drawback , but INMO you can work just fine with the default `:` separator , I'm working with intense jquery usage and never had any issues with the `:` (don't consider escaping it from time to time as a real issue)