# Dynamic ID on composite component in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I create a link in my composite JSF component:

```
<h:link id="menu-abc" outcome="/abc" value="ABC" />
```

The link is not within a form. However, when I look at the rendered HTML code there is a dynamically generated ID as prefix to my id:

```
<a id="j_idt33_menu-abg" name="j_idt33_abv" href="abc.xhtml">ABC</a>
```

I cannot find out where this dynamic id comes from. Any ideas?

ps: we changed the separator character from : to _

Answer (score 3):

The symptoms suggests that you *actually* don't have a custom component at all, but a composite component and that you've changed the `NamingContainer` separator character from `:` to `_` for some reason.

Composite components are by themselves [naming containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) and prepend the ID of all their children with their own ID. The simple reason is because they can be reused multiple times in a single view. If the composite component's own ID wasn't prepended, it would have resulted in duplicate IDs in the component tree.

In a *real* custom component you'd have full control over the client ID.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269) —  This doesn't exactly answer your quesiton, but this at least outlines the concrete differences; you incorrectly called a composite component a custom component.

Comment: thanks. I changed the question to composite compontent. And I finally found out that I missed an Id on the composite component usage.

Comment: The separator character change to `_` has serious implications. The autogenerated client ID of JSF uses by itself also that character. So you absolutely need to give all your components (at least, those which you'd like to reference elsewhere, e.g. h:message, f:ajax, etc) a fixed ID without that character. Otherwise `UIComponent#findComponent()` may greatly fail. Here's a related and possibly enlightening read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726653/