# How to dynamically add and remove a tab in p:tabView component

Tags: jsf, dynamic, primefaces, tabview

I am trying to add a PrimeFaces `<p:tab>` dynamically. While adding the second tab I am getting the following exception:

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID tab0 has already been found in the view".

How can I solve this?

Here is the view code:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:tabView id="tabview" dynamic="true" cache="false" 
        binding="#{testBean.tabView}" 
        activeIndex="#{testBean.activeTab}" >  
        <h:commandButton value="Close" action="#{testBean.removeTab}"/>
    </p:tabView>  
    <h:commandButton value="Add Tab" action="#{testBean.addTab}"/>
</h:form>
```

Here is the bean code:

```
public String addTab() {
    String tabId="tab"+id;
    System.out.println("Gen Id: "+tabId);
    tab = new Tab();
    tab.setTitle("Title: "+tabId);
    tab.setId(tabId);

    System.out.println("Tab Id: "+tab.getId());
    tabView.getChildren().add(id,this.tab);
    id++;
    return "tabtest.jsf";
}

public String removeTab() {
    tabView.getChildren().remove(activeTab);
    return "tabtest.jsf";
}
```

Comment: It seems that `id` is badly managed. Could you post more code (declaration of `id` for example) ? BWT, your methods can return `void` if you want to stay on the same page `tabtest.jsf`.

Comment: @janasoft : could you let us know how you managed to solve this (if it has been solved now) ?

Answer (score 13):

Don't manually create components if everything can just be done in the view. This construct will fail if the bean is in a broader scope than the request scope. See also e.g. [Binding attribute causes duplicate component ID found in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101755/im-getting-duplicate-id-error-after-adding-binding-attribute/2101768#2101768)

Follow the showcase example "[TabView with Model](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewModel.jsf)" which allows you to dynamically populate tabs via a sane model and `<p:tabView value="..." var="...">` like as `<ui:repeat>`/`<h:dataTable>`.

E.g. this view

```html
<h:form>
    <p:tabView value="#{bean.tabs}" var="tab">  
        <p:tab title="#{tab.title}">
            #{tab.content}
            <p:commandButton value="Close" action="#{bean.remove(tab)}" update="@form" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>  
    <p:commandButton value="Add Tab" action="#{bean.add}" update="@form" />
</h:form>
```

with this controller

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private List<Tab> tabs;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tabs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add() {
        tabs.add(new Tab("tab" + tabs.size(), "some content"));
    }

    public void remove(Tab tab) {
        tabs.remove(tab);
    }

    public List<Tab> getTabs() {
        return tabs;
    }

}
```

and this model

```
public class Tab {

    private String title;
    private String content;

    public Tab(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, I didn't know tabs can be generated that way! +1

Answer (score 0):

This is because same ID is being generated for new tab(The one which ur adding). To avoid this, append a variable to the `id` as

```
<p:tabView id="tabview_#{testBean.i}" dynamic="true" cache="false"binding="#{testBean.tabView}" 
        activeIndex="#{testBean.activeTab}" >  
        <h:commandButton value="Close" action="#{testBean.removeTab}"/>
 </p:tabView>
```

Comment: This will work by having difeerent id .can u say me the reason for voting this as not useful. share your code