# JSF 1 gridpanel getter method doesn't get called on load second time

Tags: jsp, jsf, session, tomahawk

[Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/index.html) library has been used in the legacy J2EE web application . The jsf page contain the below line ( gridpanel control) :

```
 <h:panelGrid binding="#{BasicUnavailability.gridPanel1}" id="gridPanel1" border="0" columns="8" width="100%"/>
```

There are comboboxes inside gridpanel which would be generated dynamically by the getter method which does processing and adds comboboxes to the gridpanel and return it :

```
 public HtmlPanelGrid getGridPanel1()
{
    //some processing 
    //add comboboxes to grid
   return gridpanel1;
}
```

And the setter :

```
public void setGridPanel1(HtmlPanelGrid gridPanel1) {
        this.gridPanel1 = gridPanel1;
    }
```

> When this page loads for the very first time gridpanel1 getter  method
>   is called and filled with comboboxes. It uses some session scoped bean
>   also for processing.  When we navigate away from this page and come
>   back to this page this getter method doesn't gets called and earlier
>   populated gridpanel will be shown .

This problem seems to be related with [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101755/im-getting-duplicate-id-error-after-adding-binding-attribute/2101768#2101768).But I am not able to figure out the problem with JSF1.0 . Please provide your valuable suggestion .