# component with duplicate id found

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, duplicates, identifier

I'm getting this error on simple form which has no bindings:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: component with duplicate id "frmLogin:j_id6" found
```

I've enabled debug mode and can't find such component id in there. I do see few components with ids like:

```
 id="j_id604072674_256cebae"
```

But they are all different.
How do I find what component this id is referring to? And how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Without anymore information (code), I can't help you with much more than to point you to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101755/im-getting-duplicate-id-error-after-adding-binding-attribute/2101768#2101768

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aquillo. The problem was solved by using Apache MyFaces 2.1.11
The issue was presented when I was using MyFaces 2.0.2.