# Duplicate Id is presented in view JSF and primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my project I am using Primeface 5.1 and JSF 2.2.

In my page has u`serDetail.xhtml` and `usersProfession.xhtml`. When I press click on menu to open `UserDetail` Page.

I have do some action in that page and press next menu (`userProfession` Page) it will open when userDetail not found that page to button rendered when I add button to open dialog box and include user detail page, that time I face Duplicate Id, It will already presented in view error shown.

My doubt is empty user detail occurred necessary to include page.

**Note: I tried**

1)`<f:verbatim>` to `ui:include`.

2)`f:subview` add with both page.

3)`PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` true and false.

4)`ui:fragment` also.

**userDetail.xhtml**

```
<f:subview id="userDetail">
<h:form id="userForm">
<p:panel id="userPanel">
    ........
</p:panel>
</h:form>
</f:subview>
```

**userProfession.xhtml**

```
<f:subview id="userProfessionView">
<h:form id="userProForm">
<p:commandButton onclick="PF('userDetailDialog').show();" rendered="#{empty user.userDetailList}/>
</h:form>
<p:dialog widgetVar="userDetailDialog" >
<ui:include src="/pages/userDetail.xhtml"/>
</p:dialog>
</f:subview>
```

Error Show duplicate id presented in view

Comment: Could you include some code?

Comment: Post problematic code in MCVE format: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info Otherwise, this is just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101755/binding-attribute-causes-duplicate-component-id-found-in-the-view/