# Binding attribute causes duplicate component ID found in the views

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The problem is that it says that there is a duplicate component the only thing the bean is used to record and for the edit and the component is not a. 
is tabview 
Just a portion of the code of the page since it did not let me show everything

```html
<p:tab title="Dirección"  id="tabDireccion" disabled="#{inicioPerfil.dpi== null ? inicioPerfil.disableTabDatosDireccion : 'false'}" >
                                <p:panelGrid  styleClass="no-border" style=" width: 100%;" >
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column></p:column>
                                        <p:column></p:column>
                                        <p:column > 
                                            <p:commandButton value="Siguiente" styleClass="button16 b-greylight-16" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e" style=" float: right;" 
                                                             actionListener="#{inicioPerfil.siguiente2}"   disabled="#{inicioPerfil.dpi== null ? inicioPerfil.disableTabDatosDireccion : 'false'}" process="@this,tabDireccion"  immediate="true" update="datos"  />
                                        </p:column> 
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column colspan="3"> 
                                            <p:outputLabel value="1. DIRECCIONES" styleClass="stepTitle"/>
                                            <hr/>
                                        </p:column>   
                                    </p:row>  
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column  colspan="3">

                                            <p:dataTable  styleClass="tabla-mp" id="direcciones" var="direccion" value="#{lecturaDPI.listaDireccionPersona}" editable="true" emptyMessage="No hay direcciones registradas" >
                                                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{lecturaDPI.editarDireccion(direccion)}"   ></p:ajax>
                                                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{lecturaDPI.cancelDireccion()}"   ></p:ajax>
                                                <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{lecturaDPI.cargarDireccion(direccion.idMunicipio)}" ></p:ajax>
                                                <p:column  headerText="Tipo de dirección" width="15%"  >                                               
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output" ><h:outputText value="#{direccion.idTipoDireccion.nombre}"  /></f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{direccion.idTipoDireccion}"   converter="entityConverter"  
                                                                             required="true" style="width: 100%"  >
                                                                <f:selectItems value="#{lecturaDPI.listTipoDireccion}" var="tipoDireccion" itemLabel="#{tipoDireccion.nombre}" itemValue="#{tipoDireccion}"  />
                                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column  headerText="Calle Avenida" width="10%"  >
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{direccion.avenidaCalle}" /></f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <p:inputText  value="#{direccion.avenidaCalle}" onblur="value = value.toUpperCase();" style="width: 100%"  maxlength="50"/>
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column  headerText="Número de Casa" width="10%"  >
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{direccion.numeroCasa}" /></f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <p:inputText  value="#{direccion.numeroCasa}" onblur="value = value.toUpperCase();" style="width: 100%"  maxlength="50"/>
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column  headerText="Zona" width="5%"  >
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{direccion.zona}" /></f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <p:inputText  value="#{direccion.zona}" onblur="value = value.toUpperCase();" style="width: 100%" maxlength="2"/>
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column  headerText="Colonia" width="15%"  >
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{direccion.colonia}" /></f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <p:inputText value="#{direccion.colonia}" onblur="value = value.toUpperCase();" style="width: 100%" maxlength="150" />
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column  headerText="Departamento" width="10%"  >
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{inicioPerfil.getMunicipio(direccion.idMunicipio).idDepartamento.nombre}"  />
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column  headerText="Municipio" width="10%"  >
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{inicioPerfil.getMunicipio(direccion.idMunicipio).nombre}"  />
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column  headerText="Descripcion" width="15%"  >
                                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{direccion.descripcion}" /></f:facet>
                                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                                            <p:inputText  value="#{direccion.descripcion}" onblur="value = value.toUpperCase();" style="width: 100%" maxlength="150" />
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column headerText="Editar" width="5%"  >
                                                    <p:rowEditor    />
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column  headerText="Eliminar" width="5%"  >

                                                    <p:commandLink    action="#{lecturaDPI.eliminarDireccion(direccion)}" process="@this,direcciones" update="direcciones">
                                                        <h:outputText value="Eliminar" />
                                                    </p:commandLink>

                                                </p:column>
                                            </p:dataTable>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column   colspan="3">
                                            <hr/>
                                        </p:column> 
                                    </p:row>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                                <br />
                                <p:fieldset id="agregarDirecciones" collapsed="true" legend="Agregar" toggleable="true"  binding="#{lecturaDPI.fileSet}" toggleSpeed="500">
                                    <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{inicioPerfil.handleToggle}" update="datos" />
                                    <p:panelGrid id="gridDirecciones" style=" width: 100%;"  rendered="#{lecturaDPI.nuevaDireccion}" styleClass="no-border">
                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column colspan="3" width="100%" > 
                                                <p:outputLabel value="1.1 INGRESAR DIRECCIÓN" styleClass="stepTitle"/>
                                                <hr/>
                                            </p:column>   
                                        </p:row>  
                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column colspan="3" width="100%">
                                                <p:outputLabel for="idTipoDireccion" value="Tipo de Dirección: " styleClass="label-header" />
                                            </p:column>

                                        </p:row>
                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column >
                                                <p:selectOneMenu id="idTipoDireccion"  value="#{lecturaDPI.tipoDireccion}" style="width: 75%"   converter="entityConverter" 
                                                                 required="true"  >
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="(elige un tipo de Dirección)" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                                    <f:selectItems value="#{lecturaDPI.listTipoDireccion}" var="tipoDireccion" itemLabel="#{tipoDireccion.nombre}" itemValue="#{tipoDireccion}"  />
                                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column >

                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column>

                                            </p:column>
                                        </p:row>

                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column >
                                                <p:outputLabel for="calleAvenida" value="Calle/Avenida: " styleClass="label-header" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column>
                                                <p:outputLabel for="numeroCasa" value="Número de Casa: " styleClass="label-header" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column>
                                                <p:outputLabel for="zona" value="Zona:" styleClass="label-header" />
                                            </p:column>
                                        </p:row>
                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column style="width: 33%">
                                                <p:inputText id="calleAvenida"  style="width: 75%" maxlength="50"
                                                             value="#{lecturaDPI.direccionAgregar.avenidaCalle}" onblur="value = value.toUpperCase();"  disabled="#{!lecturaDPI.nuevaDireccion}" >
                                                </p:inputText>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column  style="width: 33%">
                                                <p:inputText id="numeroCasa"   style="width: 75%" maxlength="50"
                                                             value="#{lecturaDPI.direccionAgregar.numeroCasa}"  disabled="#{!lecturaDPI.nuevaDireccion}">
                                                </p:inputText>
                                            </p:column> 
                                            <p:column  style="width: 34%">
                                                <p:inputText id="zona"  style="width: 75%" maxlength="2"
                                                             value="#{lecturaDPI.direccionAgregar.zona}"   disabled="#{!lecturaDPI.nuevaDireccion}">
                                                </p:inputText>
                                            </p:column> 
                                        </p:row>
                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column>
                                                <p:outputLabel for="coloniaDireccion" value="Colonia/Residencial/Condominio: " styleClass="label-header" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column >
                                                <p:outputLabel for="departamentos2" value="Departamento: " styleClass="label-header" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column >
                                                <p:outputLabel for="municipios2" value="Municipio: " styleClass="label-header"  />
                                            </p:column>
                                        </p:row>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding attribute causes duplicate component ID found in the view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101755/binding-attribute-causes-duplicate-component-id-found-in-the-view)

Comment: I found what gives me error is this component could help me                                                                                                                                                                                                                               <p:fieldset id="agregarDirecciones" collapsed="true" legend="Agregar" toggleable="true"  binding="#{lecturaDPI.fileSet}" toggleSpeed="500">
                                    <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{inicioPerfil.handleToggle}" update="tabDireccion" />